# HttpURLConnection.connect() showing error in android

Tags: android

```
01-25 06:27:51.270 8469-8469/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-25 06:27:51.270 8469-8469/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-25 06:27:51.810 8483-8483/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-25 06:27:51.810 8483-8483/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-25 06:27:51.980 8493-8499/? E/jdwp: Failed writing handshake bytes: Broken pipe (-1 of 14)
01-25 06:27:52.150 8493-8493/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.google.android.chimera.Activity', referenced from method lq.b
01-25 06:27:52.290 8493-8493/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.a42914.map, PID: 8493
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.a42914.map/com.example.a42914.map.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                     at com.example.a42914.map.MapsActivity.onStart(MapsActivity.java:240)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2168)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
01-25 06:28:01.860 1574-1588/system_process E/WindowManager: Starting window AppWindowToken{9d7b2b80 token=Token{9d485c28 ActivityRecord{9d336b80 u0 com.example.a42914.map/.MapsActivity t42}}} timed out
```

Comment: where is code ???????? `Could not find class 'com.google.android.chimera.Activity'`

Answer (score 0):

You have a `NullPointerException` at ligne 240 in `MapsActivity.java`